# Why is my python time comparison wrong every minute?

Tags: python-3.x, time

Hello everyone Im making a time comparison project.

Basically what Im trying to do is have my code take a reading of time and then take a separate reading of time, if the system where to go to sleep for any length of time, the code will see that a time difference has occurred.

The problem that Im running into is if statement will trigger every minute with a value of 40 seconds plus the 1 second delay I  added and I don't know why.

Any thoughts?

```
import datetime
import time

while True:
    current_time_A = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("current time A ",
          int(current_time_A.strftime("%H%M%S")))

    time.sleep(1)

    current_time_B = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("current time B ",
          int(current_time_B.strftime("%H%M%S")))

    time_elapsed = ((int(current_time_B.strftime("%H%M%S"))) - (int(current_time_A.strftime("%H%M%S"))))
    print("time_elapsed = ",time_elapsed)

    if time_elapsed >= 5:
        print("time changed more then 5 seconds")
```

Here's the output you will get

```
current time A  1959
current time B  2000
time_elapsed =  41
time changed more then 5 seconds
current time A  2000
current time B  2001
1
current time A  2001
```

Comment: You can perform substractions on `datetime` object natively. `current_time_A - current_time_B` yields the difference without whole conversions you are doing.

Comment: @BijayRegmi can you explain "whole conversions" I tried googling but with no good answer.

Comment: when you do `current_time_A - current_time_B` on `datetime` objects, it yields `timedelta` object. If you want to know the difference in seconds, you can just do `time_elapsed.seconds` without needing to convert it to `int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem you're facing is due to how you're setting everything up. Basically, you're getting the 2 times' hour, minute, and second as a string, converting them to an int, and then subtracting their differences. Seconds only go up to 59 before going back to 00. So, when `current_time_A`'s second is 59 and `current_time_B`'s second is 00, the difference comes out to be 41 (because the minute changes as well).

Instead of converting back and forth between types (`datetime.datetime` -> `str` -> `int`), I suggest using `time.time()` to get the timestamp and do your calculations on that:

```py
import time

while True:
    current_time_A = time.time()
    print(f"Current time A {current_time_A}")
    time.sleep(1)
    current_time_B = time.time()
    print(f"Current time B: {current_time_B}")

    # calculate how many seconds have elapsed since the start of the program
    elapsed_time = current_time_B - current_time_A
    print(f"Elapsed time: {elapsed_time}")
    # round to the nearest second
    print("Elapsed time (rounded):", round(elapsed_time))
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Why would I be getting 41 specifically as a value? I can understand +- 1 or 59 but I dont understand why 41. I realize that 1 is part of my 1 second delay. But 40 seems like such a odd number. I did not realize that there was a lose in the string INT conversion.

Comment: @RantWhy just take a look at the numbers in your example:
```current time A  1959
current time B  2000```.
`1959` is 12:19:59 AM (00:19:59) and `2000` is 12:20:00 AM (00:20:00). `2000-1959 = 41`

Comment: I don't know why I was thinking that the time functions would be handled in base 60. I honestly thought that 60 was the largest number not realizing that the equation was being done in normal math. its hard to see your nose when its right in front of you. Thanks for showing me the mirror.